# Rails failing rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to check the title of a page, but it is failing with:

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

Here is what pages_controller_spec.erb looks like:

```
render_views

describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title",:content => "Home")
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post the full stack trace from the spec failure before it's easily diagnosable

Comment: Also, try printing out the `response.body` - might be easier to identify that way

Comment: Thanks Nevir!  How do i get the response.body in here?  Im new to rails.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

According to this, I think you need `:text` not `:content`:

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Output:  Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",:text => "Home")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x000000050c92c0>

Answer (score 0):

rspec controller tests stub the view so you can test the controller in isolation

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-12-2/docs/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default

if you check the response object it probably contains a blank string

the idea being you should test

- if the correct template rendered
- if the controller redirected correctly
- if the controller called the correct models, etc...

that being said, if you want the test to render the view, use `render_views` in the describe block

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what house9 says, you should test the title of your views somewhere else, and not in your controller specs. For instance, you can create a "requests" directory within your spec directory and test page features there. For more information on request specs:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast